# Linear combinations of points on the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, linear-transformations

I am looking for a nontrivial example of complex numbers $c_1,\ldots,c_n,\zeta_1,\ldots,\zeta_n\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|\zeta_i|=1$ for all $i$ and
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}|c_1\zeta_1^t+\ldots+c_n\zeta^t_n|=0.
$$
In this situation a "trivial" example is one where $(c_1\zeta^t_1+\ldots+c_n\zeta_n^t)_{t=0}^\infty$ is eventually identically $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible in this formulation.

If $\zeta$ is such that $|\zeta|=1$, then $t \rightarrow \zeta^t$ is a periodic function. A linear combination of periodic functions is an *almost periodic function* (please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_periodic_function and any special literature on the subject). So the functon under the limit is an almost periodic function, which can tend to zero IFF it is identically zero. Therefore, it is possible only in 'trivial' case.